# elaticsearch update doc with index api or update api.which is more efficient?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search first time.but i can not finalize which api to use for update.it can be done by update api and also index api.but in performance which one is better?

Comment: Why not try both and decide for yourself? Please ask concrete questions about specific issues; questions asking "which one is better" tend to get closed, as they attract opinionated answers.

Comment: yes i have tried with both.there is not more time difference.  but i didnt find more documentation on update api working.

Answer (score 1):

Update API and Index API are two different things. In index API , you can over-write existing whole documents but then Update API , you can change or edit parts of the documents.

Under the hood , both are marking the original document deleted and creating a new document.